Implementing Intersection Logic and Mesh Construction for Procedural Spline-Based Roads in Unity
I’m currently working on a project in Unity where I’m creating procedural roads based on splines. At present, the roads are implemented by extruding a 2D shape along a spline or a straight line, depending on the type of road.
I’m looking for advice on how to implement the logic for detecting road intersections and constructing a mesh for these intersections. Specifically, I’m interested in understanding how to determine where roads intersect each other and how to create a mesh that represents these intersections.
Are there any resources, tutorials, or materials that could guide me through this process? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Hello. Getting started questions aren't encouraged here. What have you tried? What part do you not understand?

@Engineer At the moment, I have found the edge positions of the roads and the position of their intersection using an approximate method for finding the intersection of splines. However, I am unable to determine how to correctly map vertices, as 2D shapes will be different.
